# Winning the lottery probability

Tags: probability

If one wants to find the probability of winning the lottery and the lottery asks you for 8 numbers from 58 numbers and an extra one to choose from another 22 numbers. What is the probability of winning? Do I use permutations or combinations?

Note: the order of the numbers does not matter.
The numbers can also repeat.
I've tried using combinations. This is my way of doing it: $$C(8,58)=\frac{58!}{8!50!}=\frac{1}{8!}\frac{58!}{50!}= 1916797311\cdot22=42169540842$$ Is it correct?

Comment: Can the numbers repeat?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/odds-of-winning-the-lottery-using-the-same-numbers-repeatedly-better-worse

Answer (score 1):

The mnemotechnic I've been taught is "if **p**osition matters, than it's **p**ermutaion". Since the position (order) of the numbers doesn't matter it's definitely combinations- in how many ways can you combine $n$ numbers into a set of $k$ elements, **with repetition** - this number is given by ${n+k+1}\choose{k}$. Now, to take into account that you also need the guess the additional number, you additionally multiply by $22$.

In my answer I assumed the numbers can repeat - so for example eight $1$'s with an additional $1$ is a valid lottery ticket. If withing the first $8$ numbers you choose there is no repetition (as is the case with most lotteries, because just imagine how a lottery ticket with repetition would look like, you'd have to choose **how many** of each number you take, instead of just selecting it), then indeed your formula is correct.